# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error using text() from Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, text, innertext

```py
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='result-firstline-title highlighted-domain-title']//a")
    results = []
    for i in range(len(links)):
        title = links[i].text()
        href = links[i].get_attribute("href")
        results.append(title)
        results.append(href)
```

So to sum this thing up, I made a "search bot" in selenium that opens google chrome and searches with ecosia. I then grabbed the links and sent them back into the results array. However I get this error, and it only displays on the title part

```
  File "c:/Users/icisr/OneDrive/Desktop/Bot/Searchbot.py", line 45, in get_results
    title = links[i].text()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I then tried to only use links[i] but when I try to return it back it says that I cannot concatenate a string (href) with a web element (title)

```py
str1 = ""
  for ele in results:
    str1 += ("  " + ele)
  return str1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text seems to not be a callable so just use

```
title = links[i].text
```

Answer (score 0):

### text attribute

[`text`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) is an attribute of a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) but not a method.

So you need to replace `text()` with **`text`** and your effective line of code will be:

```
title = links[i].text
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace `text()` with only `text`

```
title = links[i].text
```